# What is the right way to use the AttributeCollection.Render method?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, web-controls

I've created a web control and I want to pass the element attributes through during the render phase. I would prefer use writer.RenderBeginTag() and RenderEndTag() but this is the only way I can seem to integrate the attributes successfully:

```
public override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    writer.Write("<");
    writer.Write(this.Tag);
    this.Attributes.Render(writer);
    writer.Write(">");
}
```

Is there another way to do this without looping through the Attributes collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
writer.WriteBeginTag(this.Tag);
this.Attributes.Render(writer);
writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
```

Comment: I knew I could count on you, stackoverflow.